# VBA Code just stops in the middle execution with out completing code (NOT A HANG)

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that is copying a upwards of 1K files or so from a network drive to a SharePoint site.  When it has completed that task, It calls the following sub.  When I step through the code it seems to work fine, and it worked fine on some of the smaller lists I uploaded.  However when I just let it run it magically stops executing code and behaves as if everything has successfully been executed.  I know it hasn't because The workbook I picked to be open is still open and the workbook I am running the code from is blank.

The best I can surmise is the code stops executing right around:

`SourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate`

Because the destination sheet is still blank, I am pretty sure the cells.copy is not executing.  The only other thing I can think of is it somehow is grabbing the Destination worksheet as the source work sheet, so nothing actually gets copied and I wind up with a blank sheet.  I rule that out though as at the end of my main sub a message box is supposed to appear when things are complete and no message box appears.

Can anyone spot an issue or shed some light on what may be happening.  Frustrating that it works when stepping through. (as long as there is a break point afterwards)

```
Sub ImportIndex()

'Copies Sheet1 from a user selected workbook
'into current work book

    Dim DestinationWS As Worksheet
    Dim DestinationR As Range
    Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    Dim FilenameWB As String

    'clear sheet1 of any previous data/formats etc
    Clear_Worksheet ("Sheet1")

    'Set the location of where the sheet is to be copied to
    Set DestinationWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set DestinationR = DestinationWS.Range("A1")

    'Open the source workbook through file picker
    '****************************************************************
    'Error may occur if workbook is already open
    'Look into how to deal with this in the future
    '****************************************************************
    FilenameWB = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilenameWB)

    'Ensure "sheet1" is the active worksheet
    SourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    'Copies active wrokesheet to Destination
    Cells.Copy DestinationR

    'close the source workbook without saving changes
    SourceWB.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

I did look at the following question, but it was related to Word.  According to one comment, the most recent build seems to have solved their issue.

**Clearworksheet function** as requested

```
Sub Clear_Worksheet(Sheetname As String)
'Deletes all cells in the provide worksheet name
'currently will cause an error if the sheet does not exist
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheetname)
        .Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Range("A1").Activate 'probably do no need this activate
    End With

End Sub
```

I just re ran the code with the elimination of ACTIVATE and also having removed all stepping break points.  I also changed the copy line to 'SourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy` as suggested.  The code still stopped executing after opening the sheet and before copying the sheet to Thisworkbook.

on a side note, I also notice sometimes while stepping through the code and I do a file pick or folder pick, the code seems to terminate unless I have a break point set somewhere slightly after it.

Comment: Why have the `.Activate` line at all? `SourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy DestinationR` will do it without requiring an activate.

Comment: I will make that change and see what happens.

Comment: Can you also include your code behind `Clear_Worksheet`?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning there are no data links in the workbook being opened for copying. It is text and numbers only in the cells.

Comment: The first thing to do is change your "pretty sure" to "definitely" by doing some tests. Use `Debug.Print` to log messages to the console Also use the debugger to step through

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have been stepping through...how do you use the debugger?

Comment: Sorry, I'm guilty of not reading your post properly. Working in debug mode but not in normal mode seems to be a common thing with no resolution. Perhaps `Debug.Print` will give you a better idea of what is going on. There's no `On Error` floating around is there? And to be clear this is running on the local Excel documents? There's no fancy stuff opening documents directly from Sharepoint and operating on them?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I do not have any `on error` calls set up in other functions.  For this operation/sub am opening an excel document on a mapped w drive.  Its contents a a list of the files that other subs copy to share point.  Get back to you on the `debug/print`...does that line go right in the code?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Apparently I lied about the `on error`  I do have an `on error` line in a separate function that gets called at the start of my main program.  That function uploads all the files from the network drive to sharepoint site.  The function returns true when successful, and the on error sends it to a false value.  Do `on error` code/lines/calls (not sure what to call them) persist outside the function/sub once that function/sub is completed?

Comment: Not 100% on how much scope the on error has but I know it always causes unexpected (but logical) behavior if not managed closely.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I can easily edit/comment it out of the function.  I am now running the code on my computer at work through remote desktop, and now it is working...I find the hit and miss nature of this issue problematic.

Comment: I`m not sure why it would stop in middle with no warning, though i would follow the other suggestions for debugging. However, if I can make one suggestion... since you are clearing/copying everything, you would be better of just copying the whole sheet, then delete the previously existing one. Less fuss about setting ranges. On the other side, if you are aiming to copy a specific range, probably should look into getting lastrow/lastcolumn and define your range as such.

Comment: @DarXyde I actually wrote two functions, `FINDLASTROW` and `FINDLASTCOL` to do precisely the later part of your statement.  I think `.cells.copy` was the first approach I came across.  In this case, since there are no formulas, conditional formatting, links or the like I am open to other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've commented that not sure why it would stop... having a wild guess it could be because of the very large range you're copying (the whole sheet...).

You should either set the range of what you are copying (cell 1 to last row/column), or in this case, since you are not adding to pre-existent data, could be better off to just copy the sheet.

See if rewriting your code this way would help?

```vb
Sub ImportIndex()
'Copies Sheet1 from a user selected workbook
'into current work book

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    Dim FilenameWB As String

    'Open the source workbook through file picker
    On Error Resume Next
    FilenameWB = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilenameWB)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not SourceWB Is Nothing Then
        'ws.Name = "something else" 'rename this if you want to keep "Sheet1" name from the source workbook
        SourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=ws
        ws.Delete

        'close the source workbook without saving changes
        SourceWB.Close savechanges:=False
    Else
        'Some error handling here... msgbox/debug.print etc
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

PS: Note that there are various ways to handle opening a workbook, but for simplicity reasons, this should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach.  I will try this out tomorrow or monday and let you know if the results change.  On a side bar here, that while I may wind up renaming the sheet, it wont be technically sheet (1) in terms of sheet indexing anymore?  I am always referencing by sheetname name when I reference, so it should not be an issue.  If I wanted the new sheet to take the place of the of the deleted sheet in the sheet index what syntax/command would be used to assign a specific index number?

Comment: You can acces the `sht.Index`, but not sure about changing, and not at home to test. I can see scenarios where you would need the index for looping, but either referring by name or a `for each` loop are usually the popular approach (though I can't provide a specific source for this claim, other than experience and observation of others code).